# Type Error, object cannot be interpreted as an index with tk message box bind commands

Tags: python, tkinter

When i run the below code and try to use the enter and leave bind commands i get the error "Type Error, object cannot be interpreted as an index". Any idea what is going on and why i cannot iterate through the list and assign each message object its own bind commands?

thanks!

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import ttk

root = Tk()
frame1= ttk.Frame(root)
textData = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
ToCNames= []
for i in range(0,len(textData)):
    ToCNames.append(Message(frame1,relief='flat',text=textData[i],width=90,font=('Arial',13,'bold')))
    ToCNames[i].bind('<Enter>',lambda index=i:ToCNames[index].configure(foreground='blue'))
    ToCNames[i].bind('<Leave>',lambda index=i:ToCNames[index].configure(foreground='black'))
    ToCNames[i].grid(column=0,row=i,sticky=(N,W))

frame1.grid(column=0,row=0)         
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bind command is passed an `event` argument, which in this case is assigned to `index` in the `lambda`, replacing the index default.

Extend your lambda to accept that argument separately:

```
ToCNames[i].bind('<Enter>',lambda e, index=i:ToCNames[index].configure(foreground='blue'))
ToCNames[i].bind('<Leave>',lambda e, index=i:ToCNames[index].configure(foreground='black'))
```

Instead of dereferencing the index in the lambda, you can just bind in the message object:

```
for i, t in enumerate(textData):
    m = Message(frame1, relief='flat', text=t,
                width=90, font=('Arial',13,'bold'))
    m.bind('<Enter>', lambda e, m=m: m.configure(foreground='blue'))
    m.bind('<Leave>',lambda e, m=m: m.configure(foreground='black'))
    m.grid(column=0, row=i, sticky=(N, W))
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn Pieters for the response, I am quite new to Python and was wondering if you would mind elaboreintg on the (for i, t in enumerate(textData):) Line and how it works? Also, why is it you can assign m to the message and still point to it later when i the bind function is called? does it not get confused and just point to the last m defined?

Comment: @Mathieas: [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) just adds an index to an existing loop; if you want both the objects in the `textData` list *and* an index (for `row=i` in the `m.grid()` call), then `enumerate()` is much more readable than using a loop over `range()` (which only produces indices).

Comment: @Mathieas: the `m` is bound as a keyword argument to the `lambda` object; the moment the `lambda` function is created it stores a reference to the `Message()` object; when called it is that reference that is used for the `m.configure()` call.